# People that don't reply after receiving an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new at SO but even so there is something annoying me: when you waste your time carefully answering a question and, after one day, one week or one month, the person that made the question don't bother to drop a single line! This is very frustrating, and I bet a lot of you guys experienced the same.

I searched the guidelines but I couldn't find anything about this matter. We know that this is just common sense and good manners, but maybe it'd be a good idea explicitly saying that the person that asks a question, after receiving an answer (or a comment), has to:

- Accept it
- Upvote it
- Downvote it
- Writing a comment
- Do something!

Maybe, in a harsher rule, losing some points after a time (let's say, a week) if the person that made the question fails to take any action.

PS: feel free to tag as a duplicate, but I couldn't find this problem here in meta.

Comment: You can't lose points if your reputation's already 1.

Comment: There is no requirement that a poster acknowledge your answer in any way. There's no requirement to vote, comment, accept, or anything else. The site's intent is to share knowledge freely to build a knowledge base. If you're answering questions for any other reason, you're bound to be disappointed; the vast majority of questions that are asked here are by 1-question wonders (stop by, ask a question, get an answer, and either never come back or create a new account the next time they do). Get used to it. :-)

Comment: I like when months or years later, there's a comment on that forgotten answer "hey, this helped a lot", or when you check how many views it had... but yes, takes time to get used to OPs that don't even give an upvote "thanks" when we put effort on the answer

Comment: This will be one of reason site looses good answerer responses and lot of questions remains unanswered. Site motto is not loosing content(quantity) but it should not compromise with quality. I have seen many people responses are very quick until they get answer and they will not even think about leaving a comment it helped them or not. I think downvoters and people who say there is no requirement that a poster acknowledge bla bla bla.. [has  not seen this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Where it is clearly mentioned "Post the question and respond to feedback"

Comment: [This link clearly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). **After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!**  But there is no attempt to prevent by site or intimate OP to respond or feedback. Looks like site aims at quantity than quality.

Comment: As people who visits site look at whether answer helped OP or not. That will put them in confusion and they may not try the suggested solution they may end up in asking a new question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, that's annoying.

No, you (and we) can't force people to do anything with an answer.

Nor should we. Just as some questions are so bad they can't be answered or don't deserve answers and should just be closed, some answers are so bad, off-topic, or non-answers that they should be downvoted, deleted, or just ignored. Forcing an OP to engage with every answer - or even just the first answer - would just annoy the OP, lead to even more one-hit-wonder abandoned accounts, and result in more clutter on the site. (It's similar to the reasoning for not requiring comments on up/down/close/whatever votes.)

Help vampires (the term for what you're describing) don't tend to get much help, anyway, because they either (1) post a garbage question or two, then disappear, or (2) post so many that we all know who they are and avoid them. In my experience, the questions tend to be *really* bad, too, to the point that it's often not possible to handle them anyway.

And, as Makoto said, you can't really do much to penalize somebody who already only has 1 reputation.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yeah, that's annoying, but there's not much to be done about it. Sometimes, people just don't find an answer helpful and don't have much to say about it. Sometimes, people forget they've gotten an answer. But whatever the reason the OP hasn't responded, there's not much constructive that we can do to prompt them. You can, of course, always leave a gentle reminder in the form of a comment (but just one time, please!).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You see, I upvoted AND I made a comment on your answer!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado :) thanks.